# laravel Error: Your PHP version is not compiled with zip support

Tags: php, laravel, zip

i am using zipper to create zip file in laravel 5.3,
  getting the error as ,

> Error: Your PHP version is not compiled with zip support

PHP version : 5.6

```
chmod($withdrawalFilePath, 0777);
$files = glob($withdrawalFilePath . '/*');
Zipper::make($withdrawalFilePath . '/Withdrawal.zip')->add($files)->close();
chmod($withdrawalFilePath . '/Withdrawal.zip', 0777);
```

Comment: maybe this could help https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=52369

Comment: https://pecl.php.net/package/zip

Comment: You should install the php-zip extension. You can do this on Linux with `apt-get install php7.0-zip` or `apt-get install php-zip`.

Comment: i tried it many times, but it wont provide any solution

Answer (score 3):

I recently encountered this problem and was able to resolve it by intstalling the `php-zip` extension.
Make sure you restart apache after installing the extension so that it will be loaded correctly.

I was using php 7 on an amazon ec2 instance running the amazon linux ami. 
The command I used was:

`sudo yum install php70-zip && sudo service httpd restart`

The command will be different depending on the version of php you have and which linux distribution you are using.

Comment: i am restricted to use php 5.6

Comment: @VivekChaudhari For php 5.6 the package is called `php-zip`